# How to add a project or target to msbuild solution that builds other projects in the same solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild, msbuild-task

Wondering if there is an easy way to do what I want with Visual Studio solution.
I have a solution that has 10+ VC++ projects. These projects don't have any dependencies on each other. I want to create msbuild target on the solution that goes and builds all the sub projects.

Something like:

**msbuild mysolution.sln /t:RebuildAll /p:Configuration=Debug**

How do I add "RebuildAll" target to my solution that iterates all projects in the solution and invokes "Rebuild" target on them?

Thanks

Comment: `build`, `clean`, and `rebuild` are supported targets on a .sln file. Are you saying that `msbuild mysolution.sln /t:build /p:Configuration=Debug` doesn't build every project in the .sln? What project(s) does the command build?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description I make some test, you can refer to the following steps:

1. Create a file named test.proj
2. Use this code in the file, remember to change your own solution path in the code:

   ```
   <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
      <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectFile Include="Your solution path/**/*.vcxproj">
        <Properties>Configuration=Release</Properties>
        </ProjectFile>
      </ItemGroup>
      <Target Name="BuildAll">
        <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectFile)" BuildInParallel="true" />
      </Target>
   </Project>
   ```
3. Then use this msbuild command line to build your projects `msbuild test.proj -t:BuildAll -v:normal -m:30`.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. This approach has a caveat. Building a project directly doesn't take into account the dependencies the project has. It only builds subset of all the dependencies. Our solution has more than 100 projects with C# and C++ projects. Building a C# project directly doesn't seem to build C++ projects. If you do the same through Solution .sln file, then all the dependencies get built and copied as expected.